# knockout template from string must create a custom binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want create a universal table components by knockout.this component must support custom template show if have a params 'templ' :

```
tableParams = {
           ...
                {
                    title: 'factory', name: "FAC_NO", isKey: true,
                    templ: '<span style="color:red" data-bind="text:FAC_NO"></span>',
                    validation: {
                        required: true,
                        maxLength: 4
                    }
                }
...
```

I want support template by string not by `<script type="text/html"...` .but knockout.js not support it? 
now I write a bind:

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.templ = {
        'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var setting = valueAccessor();
            var compile = function (html) {
                var cell = $(html);
                ko.applyBindings(setting.data, cell[0]);
                $(element).html(cell);
            };
            compile(setting.tpl);
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };
```

and use in my table components cell render:

```
    <!-- ko if:$data.templ -->
 <td data-bind="templ:{ tpl: $data.templ, data: $parentContext.$data }"></td>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

It looks work.but have any better way? My custom bind is right(have Resource Leak)?

Comment: I can see two "better" ways. The intended way is to use a custom template engine (which can extend the default one). Here's [an example from the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-7-using-the-underscorejs-template-engine). Alternatively, you could improve your custom binding to only use a `DOMParser` instance and call the default template binding with the created element, to ensure maximum reuse of code.